# Count the values per key in tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input data like this:

```py
('Volvo', [23880.0, 10200.0])
('SsangYong', [11400.0])
('Fiat', [7800.0])
```

I would like to identify the counts for each key.

I have tried multiple ways as below but it did not work.

```py
for k, v in kvdata.items():
    (k, count) = (k, count(v))
    return [(k, count)]
```

The desired output should be:

```py
('Volve', 2)
('SsangYong', 1)
('Fiat', 1)
```

Comment: You mean `len(v)`?

Comment: How would you solve the problem if your input was just `[23880.0, 10200.0]` and you wanted to get the result `2`? If you don't know, can you think of something you could try typing into a search engine in order to look for an answer? Try doing that.

Comment: Hi thanks deceze and Karl for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I got the point.

```
t = (('Volvo', [23880.0, 10200.0]),
('SsangYong', [11400.0]),
('Fiat', [7800.0]))

for (k,v) in t:
    print(k,len(v))
```

Output is:

```
Volvo 2
SsangYong 1
Fiat 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your question is to wrap all cars inside a variable and modify your problematic for loop.

You have to enclose all the cars inside a variable like this:

```
car brand = (('Volvo', [23880.0, 10200.0]), ('SsangYong', [11400.0]), ('Fiat', [7800.0]))
```

Next you need to change something in your cycle. You can simplify it like this:

```
for (k,v) in car brand:
    print(k,len(v))
```

The output will be like yours, but without round brackets, commas, and quotes

**COMPLETE SOLUTION CODE**

```
car brand = (('Volvo', [23880.0, 10200.0]), ('SsangYong', [11400.0]), ('Fiat', [7800.0]))

for (k,v) in car brand:
    print(k,len(v))
```